# Average Frequency of a Value across column excel

Tags: excel, multiple-columns, frequency

I'm looking to calculate the average frequency of 0's where they exist IN BETWEEN 1's for each row. 
I have in the past used a combination of Frequency & Column functions to Calculate Average Streak (of 1's or 0's) and Max Streak (Of 1's and 0's).

[image: Data Table]

For Example, rows 2,3,4 & 6 are omitted as no sequence of 1-0-1 occurs. Rows 5,7 & 8 have sequences of 1-0-1. For these, i'm unsure as how to calculate the average count of 0's between 1's for each row.

Any help would be greatly appreciated and thanks in advance!

Cheers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get creative with array formulas. For your example, try entering this monster formula in cell `T2` as an array formula (Ctrl+Shift+Enter) and fill down.

```
=IFERROR(   2   *   AVERAGE(   IF(($B2:$R2=0)*($C2:$S2=1)*COLUMN($B2:$R2)*(COLUMN($B2:$R2) > COLUMN($B2)+MATCH(1,$B2:$S2,0)-1) - ($B2:$R2=1)*($C2:$S2=0)*COLUMN($B2:$R2)*(COLUMN($B2:$R2) < MAX(COLUMN($B2:$S2)*($B2:$S2=1)))  <>  0,  ($B2:$R2=0)*($C2:$S2=1)*COLUMN($B2:$R2)*(COLUMN($B2:$R2) > COLUMN($B2)+MATCH(1,$B2:$S2,0)-1) - ($B2:$R2=1)*($C2:$S2=0)*COLUMN($B2:$R2)*(COLUMN($B2:$R2) < MAX(COLUMN($B2:$S2)*($B2:$S2=1)))  )   ),   0)
```

Without going into too much detail, this is what is going on:

- `($B2:$R2=0)*($C2:$S2=1)*COLUMN($B2:$R2)` - this returns an array of column numbers for where the row transitions from 0 to 1 (end of streak). Similarly `- ($B2:$R2=1)*($C2:$S2=0)*COLUMN($B2:$R2)`  adds to the array the column numbers where the row transitions from 1 to 0 (start of streak), except it is being subtracted to give negative column numbers.
- Summing each pair of positive and negative column numbers will give the streak length. A total sum divided by the number of streaks gives the average streak length. More simply 2 times the Average of all the positive & negative column numbers will give the same result.
- Leading and trailing zeros in the row are a problem, so an additional mask is added to ignore them. `*(COLUMN($B2:$R2) > COLUMN($B2)+MATCH(1,$B2:$S2,0)-1)` ignores leading zeros, and `*(COLUMN($B2:$R2) < MAX(COLUMN($B2:$S2)*($B2:$S2=1)))` ignores trailing zeros.
- So the zeros are not included in the average calculation an `AVERAGE(IF(exp <> 0, exp))` is used, which unfortunately doubles the size of the formula.
- And finally, if no streaks exist an error will occur, so an `IFERROR(exp, 0)` is used.

Comment: Wonderful. Thanks a lot for the applied explanation!

Answer (score 0):

You can use for example `=COUNTIF( $B5:$S5, 1 )` to count the 1's and `=COUNT( $B5:$S5 )` to count the numbers. You can also look into the FREQUENCY function.
If this does not answer your question, try giving a smaller examples and the numbers that you expect as a result.